# Setting up DKIM for Parse.com

Tags: email, parse-platform, dns, dkim

How can I set up DKIM with the DNS record for the domain we use for mails being sent from Parse.com, like registration emails?

Parse has only this one line of instructions:
"Run the following in your terminal: `dig +short k1._domainkey.parse.com txt` for the most up-to-date DKIM value."

But what next? The output is something like this: "k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3...44Dyfnzp7zmQIDAQAB".
How does the DNS entry has to look like?

Like this?

`k1._domainkey.parse.com IN TXT "k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3...44Dyfnzp7zmQIDAQAB"`

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing through the Advanced DNS Zone Editor in cPanel. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: This seems to be correct (without the \ as @blwinters wrote): 

`k1._domainkey.parse.com IN TXT "k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3...44Dyfnzp7zmQIDAQAB"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this on your own DNS.  If your domain is company.com, a record like this in your company.com zone file should do it:

```
k1._domainkey.company.com  In  TXT "k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3...44Dyfnzp7zmQIDAQAB"
```

Just make sure that parse.com will DKIM sign the message with your company.com domain and set `d=k1`!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck, I needed to delete the \ after k=rsa for the key type to be valid.